# Unique list from dynamic range table with possible blanks

Tags: list, excel, unique, vba

I have an Excel table in sheet1 in which column A:

> Name of company
>   Company 1
>   Company 2
>  
>  Company
>   3
>  Company 1
>  
>  Company 4
>  Company 1
>  Company
>   3

I want to extract a unique list of company names to sheet2 also in column A. I can only do this with help of a helper column if I dont have any blanks between company names but when I do have I get one more company  which is a blank.

Also, I've researched but the example was for non-dynamic tables and so it doesn't work because I don't know the length of my column.

I want in Sheet2 Column A:

> Name of company
>   Company 1
>  Company 2
>  Company 3
>   Company 4

Looking for the solution that requires less computational power Excel or Excel-VBA. The final order which they appear in sheet2 don't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a slight modification to Recorder-generated code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
        With Sheets("Sheet2").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count) _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Sample *Sheet1*:

[image]

Sample *Sheet2*:

[image]

*The sort removes the blanks.*

---

**EDIT#1:**

If the original data in *Sheet1* was derived from formulas, then using PasteSpecial will remove unwanted formula copying.  There is also a final sweep for empty cells:

```
Sub Macro1_The_Sequel()
    Dim rng As Range

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count)
    With Sheets("Sheet2").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange rng
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Call Kleanup
End Sub

Sub Kleanup()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = N To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, "A").Value = "" Then
                .Cells(i, "A").Delete shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, @Gary's Student . Did you tried that on a table? I still have the blank space just below the header in sheet2. The rest seems in order.

Comment: I get my company names with a formula based on other columns of sheet1, not sure if it is relevant. Also I switched to calculation automatic and now I only get the header and a #REF! below it . I don't know what to do.

Comment: @carlos_cs  I will try to modify the code to handle **both** problems.

Comment: @carlos_cs  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: wow, it does what I want in less than 1 second. This one EDIT#1 works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method using Excel's built-in `Remove Duplicates` feature, and a programmed method to remove the blank lines:

**EDIT**

I have deleted the code using the above methodology as it takes too long to run.  I have replaced it with a method that uses VBA's collection object to compile a unique list of companies.

The first method, on my machine, took about two seconds to run; the method below: about 0.02 seconds.

```
Sub RemoveDups()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rRes As Range
    Dim I As Long, S As String
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant, COL  As Collection


Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsDest = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsDest.Cells(1, 1)

'Get the source data
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

'Collect unique list of companies
Set COL = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1) 'Assume Row 1 is the header
    S = CStr(Trim(vSrc(I, 1)))
    If Len(S) > 0 Then COL.Add S, S
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

'Populate results array
ReDim vRes(0 To COL.Count, 1 To 1)

'Header
vRes(0, 1) = vSrc(1, 1)

'Companies
For I = 1 To COL.Count
    vRes(I, 1) = COL(I)
Next I

'set results range
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1)

'Write the results
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit

    'Uncomment the below line if you want
    '.Sort key1:=.Columns(1), order1:=xlAscending, MatchCase:=False, Header:=xlYes

End With

End Sub
```

**NOTE**:  You wrote you didn't care about the order, but if you want to Sort the results, that added about 0.03 seconds to the routine.

Comment: Hi, @Ron Rosenfeld . I tried your code with my case and it does exactly what I wanted! The only thing I dislike is that it takes around 20 seconds for 10k rows.

Comment: @carlos_cs I didn't realize it would take that long, using Excel functions.  I will add another method that uses builtin VBA functions and, on my computer, runs a lot faster.

Comment: I now see #REF! in the formulas and result of sheet2. It also happened to see #REF! in the formulas of the other VBA answers I got... I don't know why this is happening. I had calculations set to manual, I am switching to automatic right now and then I'll see.

Comment: @carlos_cs In your request, **all** that you indicated was that you had a list of companies.  If you also have formulas on sheet2, and those formulas somehow refer to this list, that is a different issue.

Comment: I have a list of companies and I get those companies through formulas based on another columns of sheet1 but that is on sheet1. In sheet2 I have nothing before running the program but after running it I get formulas associated with the company and those formulas have #REF! , first the #REF! was only in the formula but now that I changed to auto it seems to affect the result too, making it also #REF!. I am re running your code but it is taking a while and I am getting error code 13. I could have explained that better in the beginning but didn't know it was relevant and wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: @carlos_cs The latest code (and previous) I supplied should not be affecting anything on Sheet1.  I suspect either your implementation of the code is not what I expected, or, in your simplification to provide an example, you omitted something important.  if you cannot figure it out, I suggest posting a link to the workbook, with confidential information removed,

Comment: Hi, I ran your new code today and It works well in under a second while it is the unsorted version! However, when I try to sort it (uncommenting the below line in your code) I get the header also sorted and not in the first row.

Comment: @carlos_cs Just add the `Header` named argument to that line, and specify that you have one.

Comment: Can you do that please? I am not sure how to add it.

Comment: I've edited my answer.  However, if you use Help for the `Sort`method, or intellisense, it should show up.

Comment: It now works perfectly in under a second! I don't know what you are talking about with Help for sort method or intellisense but I will search that.

Comment: I think I now know what you mean with that . One more thing @Ron Rosenfeld , how do you measure the time to the hundredth of a second? I would like to test  all the answers I got to see which one is faster because counting with my head is not very accurate. Can you provide me some help/link to make a code to time my answers?

Comment: @carlos_cs Chip Pearsons web site has information on Windows timers which have millisecond accuracy.  And your machine likely also has a hi resolution timer with even better accuracy.  There are a number of links that will come up if you search for something like "VBA: Hi resolution timer"

Answer (score 1):

All of these answers use VBA.  The easiest way to do this is to use a pivot table.

First, select your data, including the header row, and go to Insert -> PivotTable:

[image: Select Data]

Then you will get a dialog box.  You don't need to select any of the options here, just click OK.  This will create a new sheet with a blank pivot table.  You then need to tell Excel what data you're looking for.  In this case, you only want the `Name of company` in the Rows section.  On the right-hand side of Excel you will see a new section named `PivotTable Fields`. In this section, simply click and drag the header to the Rows section:

[image: Creating Pivot Table]

This will give a result with just the unique names and an entry with `(blank)` at the bottom:

[image: Result]

If you don't want to use the Pivot Table further, simply copy and paste the result rows you're interested in (in this case, the unique company names) into a new column or sheet to get just those without the pivot table attached.  If you want to keep the pivot table, you can right click on Grand Total and remove that, as well as filter the list to remove the `(blank)` entry.

Either way, you now have your list of unique results without blanks and it didn't require any formulas or VBA, and it took relatively few resources to complete (far fewer than any VBA or formula solution).

Comment: Hi, @tigeravatar . That does exactly what I asked and it is actually the fastest (only needs a macro to autorefresh but I've done that before). My only concern is that because data is in a pivot table it might be more difficult or mess with my future developments but for this question in particular it was on point.

Answer (score 0):

With two sheets named `1` and `2`

Inside sheet named: `1`

```
+----+-----------------+
|    |        A        |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | Name of company |
|  2 | Company 1       |
|  3 | Company 2       |
|  4 |                 |
|  5 | Company 3       |
|  6 | Company 1       |
|  7 |                 |
|  8 | Company 4       |
|  9 | Company 1       |
| 10 | Company 3       |
+----+-----------------+
```

Result in sheet named: `2`

```
+---+-----------------+
|   |        A        |
+---+-----------------+
| 1 | Name of company |
| 2 | Company 1       |
| 3 | Company 2       |
| 4 | Company 3       |
| 5 | Company 4       |
+---+-----------------+
```

Use this code in a regular module:

```
Sub extractUni()
    Dim objDic
    Dim Cell
    Dim Area As Range
    Dim i
    Dim Value

    Set Area = Sheets("1").Range("A2:A10") 'this is where your data is located

    Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'use a Dictonary!

    For Each Cell In Area
        If Not objDic.Exists(Cell.Value) Then
            objDic.Add Cell.Value, Cell.Address
        End If
    Next

    i = 2 '2 because the heading
    For Each Value In objDic.Keys
        If Not Value = Empty Then
            Sheets("2").Cells(i, 1).Value = Value 'Store the data in column D below the heading
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The code return the date unsorted, just the way data appears.

if you want a sorted list, just add this code before the las line:

```
 Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets("2")

    sht.Activate
    With sht.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A:A")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

This way the result will be always sorted.

(The subrutine would be like this)

```
 Sub extractUni()
    Dim objDic
    Dim Cell
    Dim Area As Range
    Dim i
    Dim Value

    Set Area = Sheets("1").Range("A2:A10") 'this is where your data is located

    Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'use a Dictonary!

    For Each Cell In Area
        If Not objDic.Exists(Cell.Value) Then
            objDic.Add Cell.Value, Cell.Address
        End If
    Next

    i = 2 '2 because the heading
    For Each Value In objDic.Keys
        If Not Value = Empty Then
            Sheets("2").Cells(i, 1).Value = Value 'Store the data in column D below the heading
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets("2")

    sht.Activate
    With sht.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A:A")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

If you have any question about the code, I will glad to explain.

Comment: Hi, @Elbert Villarreal . I tried the sorted version of your code with my case. I get a blank space in first row, header in second row and the rest of the list unsorted below the header. I don't know why this is happening. I get my company names  with a formula based on other columns of sheet1, not sure if it is relevant.

Comment: your results have no formula and all remains the same after I changed to calculation automatic though.

Comment: Are that blank cells a really blank??? Or may a space, or a non printable caharacter? And if you refresh your data, you can run againg the macro and return the unique cells.

Comment: Hi, I reruned your code today and I get an empty first row, then I get everything (including header) in alphabetical order. I believe it is a real blank but as it is manual input from people I can never be sure. In this case though I believe it is a real blank because when I click that cell I can't delete anything from it. Your code takes around 7 seconds to complete. The header should be in the first row and the rest should be sorted below.

Comment: Hi I run ur code just now, it took me 3 seconds. In the Area range I picked a2:a999999 because I can never know the length of the column. Then I only changed the sheet names accordingly. I get a blank cell in the first row (can't delete anything from it) and the rest of the list unsorted below the first row. No header found in the list (yesterday and some minutes ago I picked range a:a btw).

Comment: Hey, follow me on twitter elbertv, I would like to help you.

Comment: And if you do not know the last cell of the data, in VBA would be easy to get the last row. Declare a var named `LastRow` then use this: `LastRow = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).row` that will give the last row of the data because, y like you go to cell `A1048576` and press CRTL+UpArrow.

Comment: And just one more thing,  if the user use SPACE or any other non printable character, it is posible to check that, and clear that cell or avoid it. Just follow me on twitter "elbertv" and send me a DM